# Partitioning Ubuntu dual-boot windows 10 BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm at Windows 10 and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04. Right now, I have 140GB of unallocated space. I can only use one more partition due to the 4 partitions limitations. I'm aware that I could create a logical partition and inside it place the two partitions I want: OS and swap. The problem is that I don't know how to do it, because I have no experience in Ubuntu. If I create a logical partition I would not be able to create anything more. If I'm able to use gparted, how could I set things up, step-by-step, mount points, etc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an extended partition that uses all unallocated space. Boot up the installer and tell it to use the unallocated space. It will create the logical drives and mount points automatically. install grub to the MBR to over write the windows loader.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 original from the manufacturer? If so you have a UEFI PC (not BIOS), Windows installed in UEFI mode => GPT instead of MBR ("msdos") => No such limitation regarding the number of partitions. Otherwise proceed as above but prefer newer releases like 16.04 LTS as there's no reason for individuals to use older releases.